# Laravel - How to Pass a variable to controller and to url name of route

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, translation, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I need to pass variable to controller of details of Boat and show it in the url.

This is the blade view where I download a list of boats available:

```
 @foreach($Boats as $boat)
                            <article class="box">
                                <figure class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a title="" href="{{asset('frontend')}}/ajax/cruise-slideshow-popup.html" class="hover-effect popup-gallery"><img width="270" height="160" alt="" src="{{ json_decode($boat->images, true)['url']}}"></a>
                                </figure>
                                <div class="details col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                        <h4 class="box-title pull-left">{{$boat->name}}<small>{{$boat->id}}</small></h4>
                                        <span class="price pull-right"><small>from</small>$239</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="character clearfix">
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 cruise-logo">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/110x25" alt="" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 date">
                                            <i class="soap-icon-clock yellow-color"></i>
                                            <div>
                                                <span class="skin-color">Date</span><br>{{$boat->year}}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-5 departure">
                                            <i class="soap-icon-departure yellow-color"></i>
                                            <div>
                                                <span class="skin-color">Departure</span><br>{{$boat->homeBase}}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                        <div class="review pull-left">
                                            <div class="five-stars-container">
                                                <span class="five-stars" style="width: 60%;"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <span>270 reviews</span>
                                        </div>
                                       <a href="{{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL(null, trans('routes.detailedBoat'),['id' => $boat->id]) }}" class="button btn-small pull-right">select cruise</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                            @endforeach
```

This is route route.php file to translate url:

```
return [
"login"    =>  "login",
"register"  =>  "register",
"listBoats" => "boats",
"contact" => "contact",
"detailedBoat" => "DetailBoat/{id}",
```

];

web.php :

```
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.detailedBoat'),('DetailedBoat'), function (\App\Boat $id) {
return $id;
```

});

DetailsBoat Controller:

```
public function __invoke($id)
{
    echo $id;

    return view('frontendViews.detailedBoat');
}
```

Result should be

> `http://localhost:8000/en/boats/{id}`

The strange thing is that routes work perfectly based on app.php 'locale' setting, if i have 'en' i get http://localhost:8000/en/DetailBoat/1` and http://booking:8888/it/DettaglioBarca/%7Bid%7D switching language;
viceversa if have ['it'] on app.php i'm getting http://booking:8888/it/DettaglioBarca/1 and http://booking:8888/en/DetailBoat/%7Bid%7D in english.

Thank you